# Number of permutations in Fisher-Pitman test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, permutation-test

I would like to compare the means of two independent samples of sizes $n_1 = 2$ and $n_2 = 6$ respectively. I was suggested to use a two-sample Fisher-Pitman permutation test, because it does not require any hypothesis on distributions.

From what I understood, the test statistic is computed for each possible permutation of all my observations in order to get an empirical probability density function. In my case, the number of permutations is $(2+6)! = 40320$. So the lowest p-value that can be calculated is equal to $1/8!$, wich is around $2 \cdot 10^{-5}$. In other words, the p-value I'll get will be given $\pm 2 \cdot 10^{-5}$, which is great I guess since a common significance criteria in my field is $p < 0.05$.

**What I do not understand is why we are considering all $(n_1+n_2)!$ possible permutations, instead of the $\binom{n_1+n_2}{n_1}$ combinations.**

Let me explain with an example: let's name my observations $X_1, ..., X_8$. Among all $8!$ permutations, we will get one where $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$, $X_4$, $X_5$, $X_6$ are assigned to one group, and $X_7$, $X_8$ to the second group. Then, there will also be one permutation were $X_1, ..., X_6$ are attributed similarly to one group, and $X_8$, $X_7$ are attributed to the second. These two permutations are not the same, since the order of $X_7$ and $X_8$ within their group changes. Yet, when the T test statistic is computed, these two permutations will have the same value. Aren't we taking into account two times the same thing?

If we were to actually consider combinations instead of permutations, the p-value would be given $\pm 1/\binom{8}{2} = 1/28 \approx 0.04$. So, in this case it does not really make sense to check whether my p-value is below the $0.05$ thresehold.

Comment: Why do you believe it to be the case that "the test statistic is computed for each possible permutation of all my observations"? Is this simply because the name of the procedure contains the word "permuation" or do you have some stronger basis?

Comment: @Glen_b What I understood from the references I read before posting here, is that it was permutations, not combinations, hence my question. However, when looking again in order to give you these references, I found others where it is explicitely stated that the procedure uses combinations, which make more sense to me. So thank you for making me have a second look. I'll try and make an answer to my question, as soon as find the time.

Comment: It's not observations that are permuted, but - for example - group-labels. By taking all possible assignments of such labels (or whatever else becomes exchangeable under the null but not under the alternative) you can generate the permutation distribution for the null.